# how to get post meta wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i add  this meta

```
update_post_meta( get_the_id() , 'value'.date("y-m-d-h") , 'example');
```

now how can get this meta - maybe value meta have many records .

i want get one by one value meta from post like

1- value2022-09-01-01   example

2- value2022-09-01-02   example

3- value2022-09-01-03   example

4- value2022-09-01-04   example

5- value2022-09-01-05   example

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do this for get postmeta in today:

```
key = 'value'.date('y-m-d').'-0';
counter = 1;
do {
  post_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),key.counter);
  counter ++;

} while(post_meta);
```